# Why can't I call a function from a separate class? Python

Tags: python

Here is my code

```
# import all the modules
from Fesnoria_Main import *

import pygame

# Setup
# change window settings
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption('Fesnoria - An epic journey.')

#define configuration variables here
HERO_MOVE_SPEED = 20  # pixels per second
MAP_FILENAME = 'resources/tmx/Fesnoria Town.tmx'   
MUSIC_FILENAME = "resources/music/Forest_Song.mp3"

gamesetup = Main()
gamesetup.run()
```

I want to call the function run() inside of the Main() class in my other python module Fesnoria_Main, which looks like this

```
class Main(object):
   def run(self):
       print "start game"
```

But when I run the script I get an error

```
NameError: name 'Main' is not defined
```

But it clearly is define because I imported the module at the top and also in my IDE it recognises that Main() is a class in the module Fesnoria_Main

So any ideas on how i can fix this?

Comment: what happens when you try to import only Main? `from Fesnoria_Main import Main`

Comment: it is just a guess but maybe you have not added the module in the packages __ init __.py to the __ all __ list?

Comment: Except from the `pygame` parts it seem to work as expected, it prints "start game". You should probably post an minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This minimal example is working for me:

Files:

1. bla.py
2. Fesnoria_Main.py

Fesnoria_Main.py content:

```
class Main(object):
   def run(self):
       print "start game"
```

bla.py content:

```
# import all the modules
from Fesnoria_Main import *

gamesetup = Main()
gamesetup.run()
```

Then run it with:

```
python bla.py
```

This prints:

```
start game
```

So I would try starting out with this minimal example and then work your way back to find your error.